# Linux Server (Ubuntu 20.04) restarting sometimes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, system-administration

I have a `ex62nvme` server from Hetzner.

Sometimes it automatically restarts. When I trying to connect via SSH it don't accept my password and I can only go restart server from Hetzner panel.

The projects are running on this server all is Python and Docker.
how should I troubleshoot this?

Here is an `htop` screenshot if that helps:

[image: Screenshot.]

Comment: If you have multiple Python apps running, turn them all off and only run one at a time and see what’s up.

Comment: Use **atop** to analyze historical data - how the server was loaded and what it was loaded with.